# Apple macOS Big Sur / Apple Music / Bluetooth / Amazon Echo

Tags: macos, bluetooth, music

Here's my setup: MacOS running Apple Music. Echo Dot connected by wire to an amplifier / speaker. Echo is bluetooth connected to MacOS (as confirmed on Mac UI as well as when I say "Alexa Connect" and it says "Already connected to Mac".

Now, on Mac, the echo shows up as connected to Bluetooth, but it doesn’t show up as a sound/speaker option in preferences. It also doesn’t show up on the list of available output options on Apple Music. I’ve scoured the internet and found various answers which don’t work.

Question: Can I play music out of my Apple Music to play on the Alexa -- from the Mac? Or is the only choice to use voice commands or the Alexa app on an iOS device? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

If your echo is connected to your Mac you should be able to go System Preferences - Sound and one of the options should be Echo to play your music from your echo speakers. If you don't see Echo, go to Bluetooth under System Preferences and look for Echo. Beside this is a connect button.  Click on this and then go to Sound under System Prefs.

Comment: Thanks. I did all that... but no luck. The echo does show up as connected to Bluetooth, but it does not show up on preferences/sound!

Comment: same problem. This answer is not useful for me.